# WooCommerce: How do I remove The Zip/Post Code in the Local Pickup option under shipping calculator

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two shipping options, that is Local Pickup and Local Delivery, Under shipping calculator, the zip/postcode field appears in both the options. I need help with getting rid of the zip code field in the Local Pickup option but still keep the same field in the Local Delivery option. I managed to remove it but it removes the field in Local Pickup as well as Local Delivery Option. Any help would really be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Could you paste a link so that we can suggest you a better approach.

Comment: sorry but i am running it on my local machine currently, the site isn't live yet

Comment: If you are using jQuery to hide the ZipCode Field on Local pickup then you need to write a code to unhide the same when the Local pickup option is not opted/changed to other by the user.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want hide zip code in your checkout form of woocommerce. For hide inputs you must copy this code in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    return $fields;
}
```